# Variables passed via session from a ZEND page to a PHP native page

Tags: php, zend-framework, native, session-variables

Do you think is it possible from a Zend session to pass a variabiles to a php native page session?
The 2 pages are on the same server on the same domain, because I don't want to send the variables through the url.
Thx!!

Comment: Looks like you should be reading though the Zend documentation, this is on the basic features page for the Zend session. On StackOverflow we appricate it if you do some research before you ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

In the Zend framework [documentation for basic session usage](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html) it states that:

> Zend_Session_Namespace instances provide the primary API for
>   manipulating session data in the Zend Framework. Namespaces are used
>   to segregate all session data, although a default namespace exists for
>   those who only want one namespace for all their session data.
>   Zend_Session utilizes ext/session and its special $_SESSION
>   superglobal as the storage mechanism for session state data. while
>   $_SESSION is still available in PHP's global namespace, developers
>   should refrain from directly accessing it, so that Zend_Session and
>   Zend_Session_Namespace can most effectively and securely provide its
>   suite of session related functionality.
>
> Each instance of Zend_Session_Namespace corresponds to an entry of the
>   $_SESSION superglobal array, where the namespace is used as the key.
>
> ```
> $myNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('myNamespace');
>
> // $myNamespace corresponds to $_SESSION['myNamespace']
> ```
>
> It is possible to use Zend_Session in conjunction with other code that
>   uses $_SESSION directly. To avoid problems, however, it is highly
>   recommended that such code only uses parts of $_SESSION that do not
>   correspond to instances of Zend_Session_Namespace.

Comment: I read the Zend session page 10 times yesterday, but I don't understan the concept, sorry.

Comment: This stuff is very basic, how long have you been programming in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

In my classic php I always wrote:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = 'myname';
```

and into the second page:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name']
```

and everything works fine.
Now into the zend page (if I understood) I should write:

```
$myNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('myname');
```

but in the second php native page?
Bit confused... sorry and thank you.

ps. In the bootstrap of course there is the `Zend_Session::start()`

Comment: I explaim my situation Dvid M. I am a VB programmer but for some reason last week I had to do a school questionnaire, about 120 questions. Of course I know html, css and I use and modify my joomla sites because I know some php base commands.
So I create a simple php script with a lot of forms and with all the controls inside, it works writing on mysql and so on.
But my firend ask to my to include this little program into another zend program (not mine), but I don't know zend.
Then I started to learn zend and after 1 day I create my first little zend form using Zend_Form etc. 
...

Comment: But it too long "translate" the old php program to zend so I decided to use and iframe (B php into A zend). So now I need to pass all the variables (name, school, password, etc) from my friend zend site page (A) to tmy php native questionnaire page (B). Well the only use I made before of session was for example: <?php session_start(); if ($_SESSION['displayname'] == "") { header ( "Location: index.php" ); } in my case I use the session control to verify if someone is trying to complete a page without name and so on.

Comment: To do this in my old page php before I opened a session with session start() 

session_start();
$_SESSION['displayname'] = $_POST[displayname];
etc 

and into the page (B) I use the variable $_SESSION['displayname'] as wite above

But I really don't understat how to do the same thing with zend.
I know it is easy, but after 2 days of errors I am becoming crazy.
Thank you.